# Let $p_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime then prove that $p_n<2^n$, where $n≥2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

let us prove it by induction if n=2 then p2p2 =3 which is less than 2^2 if n=3 then p3p3 =5 which is less than 2^3 similarly it is true for p= n now if I take n= n+1, then pn+1pn+1 is less than 2^(n+1)= 2^nx2 so in this case this is also valid So tell me is this correct

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: yes @user477343

Comment: I don’t understand your remark.

Comment: now check it again @user477343

Comment: @sandeepGautam You changed the body of the question to something that is illegible now. See some [MathJax tips here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove it by induction:

If $n=2$ then $p_2 = 3 \lt 2^2$.
If $n=3$ then $p_3 = 5 \lt 2^3$.
Assume it is true for $n=k$, while $k\ge 2$. Then $p_k\lt 2^k$.
By [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) , there is a prime $p$ such that $2^k\lt p\lt 2^{k+1}$, so $p_{k+1}\lt 2^{k+1}$
The theorem follows.

Comment: Can you please add more detail about why $p_{n+1}<2^n \times 2$?Also note that $n\neq n+1$

Comment: @TonyMa Maybe because of Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: Oic, I think so